# tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempTable') getting error in Azure database

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I am getting error while using below statement.

```
Select name as ColumnName From
tempdb.sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempTable').
```

while using tempdb.sys.columns ,I am getting error if removed database name(**sys.columns**) it is  not showing any error in Azure SQL Database.Is there any solution to fetch tempdb.sys.columns in Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 3):

Three part naming wont work in SQLAZURE.so referencing TEMPDB or any cross database queries wont work in azure

There is a new service called Managed instance (Which is in preview),this feature has all the capabilties of SQLAZure like automatic patching,backups..but will include most of the capabilties of an onpremises instance like sqlagent,clr...

Answer (score 1):

I have used below statement and got result.

```
SELECT name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
('select * FROM #TempTable',NULL,0);
```

[Please check this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)